# jquery show hide each div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic number of divs which generated through asp.net. I need to show each div contents by clicking on its header. I have tried this {

```
 $(function () {
            var myHead = $(".toggle-container").find(".toggle-header");
            var myBody = $(myHead).parent().find(".toggle-content");
            $(myHead).click(function () {
                if ($(myBody).css('display') === 'none') {
                    $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-chevron-sign-down').addClass('icon-chevron-sign-up');
                    $(this).parent().find(".toggle-content").slideDown("slow");
                } else if ($(myBody).css('display') === 'block') {
                    $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-chevron-sign-up').addClass('icon-chevron-sign-down');
                    $(this).parent().find(".toggle-content").slideUp("slow");

                };
            });
        });
```

But it's working only for first header and rest of the headers doesn't collapse it's children content. Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/fmjq6/) Link what I have tried so far. Can anyone give a fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was how you were finding the content to be displayed/hidden. You need to find the content related to the clicked header you the code `var myBody = $(myHead).parent().find(".toggle-content");` should go inside the click handler as `var myBody = $(this).next()`

```
 $(function () {
     var myHead = $(".toggle-container .toggle-header");
     $(myHead).click(function () {
         var myBody = $(this).next()
         if ($(myBody).css('display') === 'none') {
             $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-chevron-sign-down').addClass('icon-chevron-sign-up');
             $(this).parent().find(".toggle-content").slideDown("slow");
         } else if ($(myBody).css('display') === 'block') {
             $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-chevron-sign-up').addClass('icon-chevron-sign-down');
             $(this).parent().find(".toggle-content").slideUp("slow");

         };
     });
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8snrV/)

*Note: Still the up-down arrows are nor working because you need to use `find()` instead of `children()`*

**But it can be simplified as**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $heads = $(".toggle-container .toggle-header");
    $heads.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('i').toggleClass('icon-chevron-sign-down icon-chevron-sign-up');
        $this.next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HLXTB/)

Comment: Are you sure using `.next()` is the best practice? Isn't it really coupled with the DOM?

Comment: @Itay any solution will be coupled with the dom... because we are finding the elements in relative to other... so `.next()` or `.closest('.toggle-container').find('.toggle-content')` all will be same and will have dom dependency

Comment: The second option you've written is much better than the first one.

Comment: @Itay that is the way to do it.... I gave the first to make the OP's solution work...

Comment: +1 But I still think you should atleast make your second example less coupled.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, can you please give a try for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521358/jquery-cookie-set-and-get-expanded-status-of-divs)? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The below would work.

In your original code you had assigned the variable `myBody` a value at the time of load itself. Since there are many such elements, it used only the first one.

Now I have moved the value setting for the `myBody` variable to be inside the `click` event and used `$(this)`. This will make sure that it always finds the element in relation to the current element that was clicked.

```
 $(function () {
     var myHead = $(".toggle-container").find(".toggle-header");
     $(myHead).click(function () {
         var myBody = $(this).parent().find(".toggle-content");         
         //console.log('yes');
         if ($(myBody).css('display') === 'none') {
             $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-chevron-sign-down').addClass('icon-chevron-sign-up');
             $(this).parent().find(".toggle-content").slideDown("slow");
         } else if ($(myBody).css('display') === 'block') {
             $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-chevron-sign-up').addClass('icon-chevron-sign-down');
             $(this).parent().find(".toggle-content").slideUp("slow");

         };
     });
 });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/fmjq6/5/)

Comment: thanks @harry. I accept Arun P Johny's answer because it has good sleek solution.