# jquery Cookie set and get expanded status of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies, jquery-cookie

I have a question and issue related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942835/jquery-show-hide-each-div-onlick) thread. I have multiple divs which are loaded dynamically through c# code. We can't count the number of panels (each category) that needed to be displayed in a webpage. It might be a single or 4 or 5 sometimes more. The previous code is working properly as expected.

Now, I want to retain the collapsed or expanded state of each div on a postback or page refresh. I tried to use jquery cookie, but we can't seem to set and get the cookie status for each sections.

The code that I have tried is

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $heads = $(".toggle-container .toggle-header");
    $heads.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('i').toggleClass('icon-chevron-sign-down icon-chevron-sign-up');
        $this.next().slideToggle("slow");
        if ($this.next().is(':visible')) {
            $.cookie('expanded', 'true');
        } else {
            $.cookie('expanded', 'false');
        }
    });
    var cookieValue = $.cookie("expanded");
    if (cookieValue === "true") {
        $heads.next().show();
    } else {
        $heads.next().hide();
    }
});
```

JsFiddle Playground: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/qL79j/

**Update:**

I tried with this also: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/qL79j/7/ . I can't change markup than this one.

Can anyone give a try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember my case when jquery.cookie worked **only** when set like this: `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });` - with the expires and path parameters.

Comment: @Tom, setting cookie is not an issue. can set and cookie values without any problem. Issue is how to set and get values for each divs.  If I use the above code, it will apply to all the divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set ID to all of your blocks and create cookie based on IDs. like this:

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qL79j/5/)

```
$('.block').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).find('.outer').css('display') == 'block' )
    {
        $(this).find('.outer').slideUp('normal');
        $.cookie($(this).attr('id'), 'hide');

    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find('.outer').slideDown('slow');
        var tab_cookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('id'));

        if ( tab_cookie == 'hide' )
        {
            $.cookie($(this).attr('id'), 'show');
        }
    }
});
```

then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.block').each(function(){
        var block =$(this).attr('id');
        if ( $.cookie(block) == 'hide' )
        {
            $(this).find('.outer').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

---

## update

in your case use this code:

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qL79j/8/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.toggle-container').each(function () {
        var block = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($.cookie(block) == 'hide') {
            $(this).find('.toggle-content').hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.toggle-content').show();  /* show visible element  */
        }
    });
    $('.toggle-header').click(function () {
        if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'block') {
            $(this).next().slideUp('normal');
            $.cookie($(this).parent().attr('id'), 'hide');

        } else {
            $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
            var tab_cookie = $.cookie($(this).parent().attr('id')); /*  missed parent() here */
            if (tab_cookie == 'hide') { 
                $.cookie($(this).parent().attr('id'), 'show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working in my case...  Please see here. http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/qL79j/7/ . In your code, you're expanding/collapsing by clicking anywhere in the container. but not in my case.